# Update table using case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table `test`

```
Id     Code        ParentId
1      R            O
2      Y            O
3      P            O
4      O            NULL
```

I need to update `test` like that :

```
   Id     Code        ParentId
    1      R            4
    2      Y            4
    3      P            4
    4      O            NULL
```

I tried that but it doesn't work , any idea ?

```
update [dbo].[test]
set [ParentId] =
CASE WHEN [ParentId]='' THEN [Id]
else select top 1  [Id] from [dbo].[PNL] where ParentId=[Code]
End
```

I got the table `test updated`

```
      Id     Code        ParentId
        1      R          NULL
        2      Y          NULL
        3      P          NULL
        4      O          NULL
```

Comment: What does the `[dbo].[PNL]` table look like? What error do you get? If no error, what is the resulting data?

Comment: Usually 'root' records have no parent - the value of `parentId` would be `null`.  Why do you want it to be a parent of itself?  This makes some queries quite unsafe, as this would be unusual (so normal queries looking for the root would cause infinite recursion).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You are absolutely right , I update my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With updates and deletes it is usually safer to first test the select:

```
    select t1.*,
    case when t1.parentid is null then t1.id 
    else (select top 1 t2.Id from #t t2 where t1.ParentId = t2.Code) end as new_parentid
    from #t t1
```

and then do the actual update using CTE:

```
with x as (
    select t1.*,
    case when t1.parentid is null then t1.id 
    else (select top 1 t2.Id from #t t2 where t1.ParentId = t2.Code) end as new_parentid
    from #t t1
)
update x
set parentid = new_parentid
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct fix is:
- Put the sub-query in `()`
- Make sure to specify `[test]` in that sub-query

*(I've had to guess whether `ParentID` or `[code]` come from `[test]`.)*

```
update [dbo].[test]
set [ParentId] =
CASE WHEN [ParentId]='' THEN [Id]
else (select top 1  [Id] from [dbo].[PNL] where ParentId=[test].[Code])
End
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the requirements are fairly simple:

- If a row doesn't have a `ParentId`, leave it alone.
- If a row has a `ParentId` matching a Code in the same table, then update the `ParentId` with the matching row's `Id`.

In such case, a simple `INNER JOIN` update should work:

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  ParentId = PT.Id
FROM
  test T
  -- The INNER JOIN will automatically discard all rows without ParentId
  INNER JOIN
  test PT ON
    (PT.Code = T.ParentId)
```